# C# TimeSpan parse

Tags: c#, parsing, timespan

I have a timespan - 15 seconds

```
TimeSpan initTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 15, 0);
```

Also a string from the timespan, which is in format as is below:

```
String s = initTimeSpan.ToString("mm':'ss':'fff");
```

How can I parse this string back to the timespan? This code doesn't work:

```
t = TimeSpan.Parse(s);
```

as it understands seconds as minutes.

Also it would be very helpful if someone could give me advice on how to format the original timespan, so that the string would be in **"ss:fff"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a `TimeSpan` based on seconds, then better use

```
var initTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
```

This is the string format to get only seconds and milliseconds:

```
initTimeSpan.ToString("ss':'fff");
```

Here is how you can parse it:

```
TimeSpan parsed = TimeSpan.ParseExact(s, "ss':'fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include hours (hh) in the response... [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9(v=vs.110).aspx) is the msdn article.

To elaborate, you would use something like

```
String s = initTimeSpan.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss':'fff");
```